# Custom Styles/UI for Browser Reader View

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, microsoft-edge

Is there a pseudo-class, media query, or another way for CSS to apply different styles when using Safari or Microsoft Edge in [Reader view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/use-immersive-reader-in-microsoft-edge-72ac6331-2795-42eb-b3e8-c03503231f32)?

I would like to explicitly hide certain UI elements if the user is using this mode, that the mode does not hide on its own, but I can't find any documentation on it.

The only indicator I could find is that Microsoft Edge changes the URL protocol to `"read:"`, and Safari changes it to `"safari-reader:"`. However, this is only detectable via Javascript, which these modes typically disable.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Safari seems to allow "some" JavaScript execution. I'm not sure exactly when, but it seems to permit style changes as the page loads and on user action. So it is technically possible to check the `location.protocol` then, but I'm hoping there is a more standardized approach.

Comment: I can use `element.style.display = "none"` to hide some elements. What're the exact "UI elements" you'd like to hide? You can explain more on your demand.